# What does it mean that "$e^{tx}$ is never zero since $e^{tx}e^{-tx}=e^0=1$, where $t$ complex and $x$ real?

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers, proof-explanation

There is a proof that starts as follows

> Let $L(y)=y''+ay'+by$. Since $f'(x)=te^{tx}$, we also have
> $f''(x)=t^2e^{tx}$, so $L(f)=e^{tx}(t^2+at+b)$. But $e^{tx}$ is never
> zero since $e^{tx}e^{-tx}=e^0=1$.

where $f(x)=e^{tx}$ is a complex-valued function ($t$ is complex, $x$ is real).

I can't quite understand the sentence

> But $e^{tx}$ is never zero since $e^{tx}e^{-tx}=e^0=1$

Comment: Product of $0$ and any complex number is $0$; it cannot be $1$.

Comment: For complex numbers, zero times anything is zero. Since there is some number that multiplies with $e^{tx}$ to get 1 for any choice of $t$ and $x$, none of those choices can make $e^{tx}$ equal zero.

Comment: So, what that sentence is saying is that if $e^{tx}=0$ for some $x$ then it must be true that $e^{tx}$ times every number is 0. But this is not true since $e^{tx}e^{-tx}$=1. So in fact this is an implicit proof by contradiction?

Comment: The sentence is saying that every value of $e^{tx}$ has an inverse.  If there were a set of values such that $e^{tx}=0$ then there would be an inverse of $0$.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a group-theoretic statement. Given that $\mathbb{C}$ is a field and *a fortiori* an (abelian) group under multiplication, the relation $e^{tx}e^{-tx} = 1$ means that $z := e^{tx}$ possesses an inverse, namely $z^{-1} = e^{-tx}$, for whatever $t$ and $x$. Since $0$, as the additive identity element, is the only element without a multiplicative inverse, one can conclude (by contradiction) that $z = e^{tx} \neq 0$.